# Vue.js 2 dynamically adding and removing classes in looped elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a project here where I need to add and remove layers of images, using vue.js 2. I am building up a pizza where I need to add toppings. My current solution has a flaw - it removes all other elements/ pizza toppings when I add a new one.

The toppings are generated from an array which I loop through.

Can you please help, I am sure this is easy but me being a rookie in vue.js I have already struggled for hours... Thanks!

```
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="left-container">
              <h2>add your ingredients:</h2>
              <div v-for="(item, index) in pizzas"  v-bind:key="index">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="show == index ? show = -1 : show = index">{{ item.pizza }}</button>
              </div>
              <div class="submit-buttons">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary reset-pizza" v-on:click="show = -1">Reset pizza</button>
                  <a href="http://fb.com" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary submit-pizza">Share pizza</button></a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-container">
              <ul class="pizza-layers">
                <li v-for="(item, index) in pizzas" class="pizza-canvas" v-bind:class="item.class" v-if="show == index"></li>
                <li class="pizza-canvas pizza-canvas--topping-base"></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<script>
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      pizzas: [
        { pizza: 'Salami', class: 'pizza-canvas--topping-salami' },        
        { pizza: 'Rucolla', class: 'pizza-canvas--topping-rucolla' },
        { pizza: 'Cheese', class: 'pizza-canvas--topping-cheese' }
      ],
      show: {},
    },
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow for multiple toppings, `this.show` should be an array, instead of an object.

Once you change that, you'd need to modify the click event handler to add/remove the topping based on whether or not the topping is already part of `show`.

Also, while displaying the topping, you'd need to check its existence using `show.includes(index)` instead of `show == index` - since `this.show` is an array.

In the snippet below, I've applied these changes, and added some background colors to visualize how the toppings are added or removed.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pizzas: [{
        pizza: 'Salami',
        class: 'pizza-canvas--topping-salami'
      },
      {
        pizza: 'Rucolla',
        class: 'pizza-canvas--topping-rucolla'
      },
      {
        pizza: 'Cheese',
        class: 'pizza-canvas--topping-cheese'
      }
    ],
    show: [],
  },
  methods: {
    addTopping(event, item, index) {
      if(this.show.includes(index)) {
         this.show.splice(this.show.indexOf(index),1);
      } else {
        this.show.push(index);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.pizza-canvas--topping-salami {
  background-color: red;
}

.pizza-canvas--topping-rucolla {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pizza-canvas--topping-cheese {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left-container">
      <h2>add your ingredients:</h2>
      <div v-for="(item, index) in pizzas" v-bind:key="index">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="addTopping(event, item, index)">{{ item.pizza }}</button>
      </div>
      <div class="submit-buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-primary reset-pizza" v-on:click="show = []">Reset pizza</button>
        <a href="http://fb.com" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-primary submit-pizza">Share pizza</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
      <ul class="pizza-layers">
        <li v-for="(item, index) in pizzas" class="pizza-canvas" v-bind:class="item.class" v-if="show.includes(index)"></li>
        <li class="pizza-canvas pizza-canvas--topping-base"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```